# Java can combine default implementation from an abstract class and interface in a class. Is there a way to achieve this in C#?

Tags: java, c#, interface, abstract-class

Is there a "smart" way to achieve the same result as in Java when using an interface and abstract class which both implements their own half of a shared interface?

In Java, I'm able to extend an abstract class (`AnAbstractClass`) and implement an interface (`AnotherInterface`) which each have a default implementation of their part of an interface (`AnInterface`), such that I don't have to implement any methods in the class that combines these (See code).

I'm trying to convert Java code to C# while making sure everything is mapped 1-to-1. So I would like to avoid creating new classes as much as possible and that my "Combiner" class doesn't contain any methods.

```
public class Test{
    
    public interface AnInterface
    {
        String methodOne();
        int methodTwo();
    }
    
    public interface AnotherInterface extends AnInterface
    {
        default int methodTwo() 
        {
            return 2;
        }
    }
    
    public abstract class AnAbstractClass implements AnInterface
    {
        public String methodOne() 
        {
            return "1";
        }
    }
    
    public class Combiner extends AnAbstractClass implements AnotherInterface
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: _"making sure everything is mapped 1-to-1"_ when "translating" code from language A to language B is not the smartest of ideas to begin with ...

Comment: @Fildor I agree, but as the java code might change in the future, I (or someone else) will have to reflect the same changes to the C# version which can be tedious if the code is too different

Comment: Then don't ... why maintain a software in 2 languages?

Comment: Because there isn't a C# version of the library, which I need in my case. So when the developers of the Java library pushes an update in 1 year I'll be able to reflect that in my C# version without having to spent extra time to figure out how/what I changed it to

Comment: The problem with "1:1" translations between specifically Java and C# is: There are certain things that are done differently - basically speaking. You **cannot** _always_ code things 1:1 the same in both languages. They have different feature sets, different core library implemenations, even different concepts sometimes.

Comment: ... and by the way: If this library is so important for your codebase - why not switch to Java for the whole project? Wouldn't that make our life easier? That would rid you off the need to maintain a "whatever-lib-in-java" clone.

Comment: ... or another way out of this would be to "simply" create an API (Rest for example) for that lib and use it like a micro-service. That would mean you'd need to run a Java-Service, yes, and I don't know how that would fit in with your project, but if I had to do this, I'd prefer it over maintaining a C# clone of 3rd party Java lib. Especially if this is a commercial project which could end up in legal trouble for exactly cloning that lib (maybe that's that's a non-issue, but who knows...).

Comment: I get your points and that what I'm doing is weird. 
But we are already using lots of C# specific libraries and everything else is C# (not feasible converting that to Java). I'm not entirely sure about the micro-service, but I think it would be too costly to have a Java-service running on each server (I can't answer why we aren't doing that). The only legal problem is that we have to publish my conversion when it is up and running. Lastly, I'm aware that I cannot always code thigs 1:1, which is why I also wrote "I would like to avoid" not "I have to avoid"

Comment: I guess I'd also try and find a library that is native to C# that has the same functionality. Unless this is very very very niche stuff, there is probably already something on nuget. Or maybe a sophisticated open soure github project that could profit from your expertise and pull requests? I mean, if you are willing to put effort into porting the whole library ...

Answer (score 0):

This is accomplishable in C#, but as far as I know there's no smart way to do it as interfaces should in general be kept simple and this would mostly just make the code harder to read and debug.

```
public interface IAnInterface
{
    public string MethodOne();
    public int MethodTwo();
}

public interface IAnotherInterface : IAnInterface
{
    public static new int MethodTwo()
    {
        return 2;
    }
}

public abstract class AnAbstractClass : IAnInterface
{
    public string MethodOne()
    {
        return "1";
    }
    public abstract int MethodTwo();
}

public class Combiner : AnAbstractClass, IAnotherInterface
{
    public override int MethodTwo()
    {
        return IAnotherInterface.MethodTwo();
    }
}
```

So I implore you to not do this!

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for a Combiner class with no code but this seems to be perfect! I'll sacrifice the readability and debugging for this case to achieve the most Java looking C# code

Comment: It seems I still have a problem as MethodTwo is static and thus can't be used on an instance of a class that implements IAnInterface which might cause problems further down the road

Comment: Then you should refactor your design instead of doing a one-to-one rewrite.